# R Error message 'argument fdef is missing with no default`

Tags: r, generics, r-s4

The following code fails with the error message shown above.

```
#' Generic setter for XiFit class
#'
#' @param knots Knots object to which weights are applied
#' @param weights Given weights
#'
#' @return Object of XiFit class
#' @export
#' @rdname XiFit_setter
setGeneric("setXiFit",
           function(knots, weights){
               standardGeneric("setXiFit")
           }
)
```

I do not understand what is missing. I have no object with the name `fdef`.

This code is in a package I wrote two years ago. I am pretty sure that the package used to work!

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: Can you try again after deleting the curly braces to get this `setGeneric("setXiFit", function(knots, weights) standardGeneric("setXiFit"))` . Having the curly braces when using `standardGeneric` is a common mistake that result in nonstandard generic function.

Answer (score 0):

`fdef`is an argument to the function `standardGeneric`. An argument is an input to a function. According to the [function description](https://www.stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/standardGeneric.html) fdef should be the function definition.

Comment: Thank you but I still don't know how to cure my problem. The function description document you refer to states "The argument fdef is inserted (automatically) when dispatching methods for a primitive function. ... Don't insert this argument by hand..." I am surely showing my ignorance of how to work with S4 methods!

Comment: Without knowing what your project is I'd guess that you're trying to call your generic method without defining it for the signature used. But I'm no expert either, maybe you'd want to define a default version of your function